# Converting NSString to Epoch timestamp iOS7

Tags: ios7, nsstring, nsdate, epoch

I need to convert the following date to epoch timestamp

Wed, 21 May 2014 16:47:00 BST

stringPubDate has the above string stored in it.

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, d MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"];

    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:stringPubDate];
```

Null is being returned when I do this. I need to convert this NSString to NSDate and then convert it into epoch timestamp. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the date format you are giving does not match the format of the date in the string.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: It's the `z` that's wrong. If you delete the `z` and the `BST` you'll see that it works. The date formatter doesn't know what `BST` means.

Comment: I received the date from a site so I haven't changed anything... anyways I just wanted to sort a set of such dates so the zone doesn't really matter...